# How can I create an instance of IVsSolution4?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I am updating a Visual Studio extension to work in Visual Studio 2022. The extension was last updated for Visual Studio 2017.

In the extension is a helper method, `ReloadProject`, used to reload a project and optionally apply an action while the project is unloaded.

```cs
static internal EnvDTE.Project ReloadProject(EnvDTE.Project proj, Action duringUnload = null)
{
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    IVsSolution sol = (IVsSolution)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));
    IVsHierarchy selectedHierarchy;
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(sol.GetProjectOfUniqueName(proj.UniqueName, out selectedHierarchy));
    Guid guid;
    sol.GetGuidOfProject(selectedHierarchy, out guid);
    sol.CloseSolutionElement((uint)__VSSLNCLOSEOPTIONS.SLNCLOSEOPT_UnloadProject, selectedHierarchy, 0);
    if (duringUnload != null) duringUnload();
    IVsSolution4 sol4 = (IVsSolution4)sol;
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(sol4.ReloadProject(guid));
    return GetProject(guid);
}
```

However, when trying to cast `sol` to `IVsSolution4` I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Solution' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution4'.
  Source=<Project Name>
  StackTrace:
   at <Project>.Utilities.DTE.ReloadProject(Project proj, Action duringUnload) in <FilePath>\Utilities\DTE.cs:line 185
   at <Project>.Features.NuGetBackedFeature.Enable(Project project) in <FilePath>\Features\NuGetBackedFeature.cs:line 41
   at <Project>.MyPackage.<>c.<InitializeAsync>b__1_6(Object sender, EventArgs e) in <FilePath>\MyPackage.cs:line 105
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommand.Invoke(Object inArg, IntPtr outArg, OLECMDEXECOPT options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommandService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& commandGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdExcept, IntPtr pIn, IntPtr vOut)
```

Every example I've found online suggests that I should be able to cast the result of `ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution))` to `IVsSolution4`, but this hasn't been working for me.

As far as I know, this approach still works in Visual Studio 2017 with the current version of the extension.

Does anyone know what the correct approach is to creating an `IVsSolution4`, or more generally, to reloading a project?

**EDIT**: Did some more experimenting, and found that the returned object implements `IVsSolution`, `IVsSolution2`, and `IVsSolution3` (i.e. it successfully casts to each of these types). I'm wondering if something changed with the definition of `IVsSolution4` in VS2022 that prevents casting.

Comment: Does [this](https://vssbe.r-eg.net/doc/Examples/ReloadProjects/) can help you about how to reloading a project?

Comment: Adapting from your link, I tried

`object service = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsSolution)); IVsSolution sln = (IVsSolution)service; IVsSolution4 sln4 = (IVsSolution4)service;`

And get the same exception trying to convert `service` to an `IVsSolution4`.